# Existence of function that blows up on a null set

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $m$ denote Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Show that for any set $E$ with $m(E)=0$, there is a non-negative integrable function $f$ such that
$$
\liminf_{m(B)\to 0}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)\ dy=\infty
$$
for each $x\in E$, where the infimum is taken over all balls $B$ containing $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the following idea. It suffices to consider the case when $E$ is a $G_\delta$-set. Let $E=\bigcap_{n\in\omega} U_n$ be an intersection of a sequence of non-increasing open sets such that $U_0=\mathbb R^d$ and $m(U_n)\le 1/4^n$ for each $n\ge 1$. Define $f: \mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^+$ by putting $f|U_0\setminus U_1\equiv 0$ and $f|U_n\setminus U_{n+1}\equiv 2^n$ for each $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Does this assign a value to points in $E$?  Seems like if $x \in E$, then $x \in U_{n+1}$ and none of your definitions apply.

Comment: Since $E$ is a null set, we don't even have to bother defining $f$ there (we're really working with equivalence classes of functions, defined up to sets of measure $0$). Alex Ravsky, I'm not sure what you mean by a sequence of "non-increasing open sets", can you clarify?

Comment: @pre-kidney They are nested, so $U_0\subset U_1\subset U_2\dots$

Comment: Uh, other way around, but you get the point.

Comment: Oh you mean $U_n \searrow E$?

Comment: @pre-kidney Yes.